# How to make your own spalted maple

Tags: wood, spalted

It is very hard to get spalted maple around my area (from Wisconsin) and I want to make my own, if possible, spalted maple. I do not know how you can make your own though, because it comes from  dead trees with fungus growing on the wood or something. But I am sure there is more to it. Is it as easy as buying maple wood, then letting it sit there? Would I cover it or leave it? How long would it take? Is the wood "treated" with something even if it says "untreated"? In the end my simple question is, how can I make my own spalted maple?